# Achievement messages in top bar are being double-HTML-encoded

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, html-entities

See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Curiously, there are older badge achievement messages further down the list which display properly.

Comment: [status-by-temporary-design](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1648828#1648828).

Comment: I find it interesting that my bug reports always result in even worse bugs... I should stop reporting. Original bug report for reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209166

Comment: @animuson Eh, I'll take this over an improperly-unencoded unclosed <marquee> tag any day of the week.

Comment: people really are _praying_ on [meta-tag:top-bar] bugs these days..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2013.11.27.1690`